# The system asks me permission to run MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, compiling, texstudio

Every time I run TeXStudio the system asks me permission to run `MiKTeX` several times, then it compiles the document.

Why is that?

Comment: Do you installed MikTeX as administrator?

Comment: Try uninstalling miktex and re-installing it as administrator. For that, right-click on the installer file and choose 'run as administrator'. After having done that, try compilation of your document again and please report back.

Comment: Or did you install a virus scanner? Then you'll need to tell it that the programs used (e.g. `pdflatex`, `makeindex` etc.) are safe.